# Add node to a XML variable and Save it

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

i want to add the xml node i.e `<name>B07BZFZV8D</name>` to the XML variable before saving it.
I want to add the 'name' node inside the 'Self' Element.

```
#Previously i use to save it directly like this, 

$Response        #this is the respnse from api

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$dom->loadXML($Response);


##saving in file
$myfile = file_put_contents('data.xml', $Response.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Answer (score 1):

With DOM you use methods of the document object to create the node and methods of the parent node to insert/add it to the hierarchy.

`DOMDocument` has `create*` methods for the different node types (element, text, cdata section, comment, ...). The parent nodes (element, document, fragment) have methods like `appendChild` and `insertBefore` to add/remove them.

Xpath can be used to fetch nodes from the DOM.

```
$document = new DOMDocument;
$document->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$document->loadXML($xmlString);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// fetch the first Data element inside the Report document element
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/Report/Data[1]') as $data) {
    // create the name element and append it
    $name = $data->appendChild($document->createElement('name'));
    // create a node for the text content and append it
    $name->appendChild($document->createTextNode('Vivian'));
}

$document->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report>
  <Data>
    <id>87236</id>
    <purchase>3</purchase>
    <address>XXXXXXXX</address>
    <name>Vivian</name>
  </Data> 
</Report>
```

Comment: hello sir thanks for your reply, this is not workiing for me i am getting the same result with no name added...i have given the proper xml file can you please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Using @ThW Code:
Need to change Create Element functionality

```
$document = new DOMDocument;
$document->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$document->loadXML($xmlString);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
// fetch the first Data element inside the Report document element
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/Report/Data[1]') as $data) {
// create the name element with value and append it
$xmlElement = $document->createElement('name', 'Vivian');
$data->appendChild($xmlElement);
}
$document->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $document->saveXML();
```

It works for me with php7.0. Check it works for you.