# Add Node to the XML Before Saving

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, xmlnode

how to add xml node `<TypeId>HDU5K3KDI23F</TypeId>` to the 'Top' node of the XML variable before saving.
XML data i am getting is coming from API as a Response.
When i use the below code,xml response data does get saved, but the 'Typeid' Node is not getting saved in that file.

## XML Response Data looks like this

```
        <GetCategories>
           <GetProduct>
               <Data>
                  <Id>87772873</Id>
                  <Name>Foods and Beverages</Name>
                  <Top>
                  <CategoryId>028392323</CategoryId>
                  <CategoryName>Categories</CategoryName> 
                  </Top>
               </Data>
           </GetProduct>
       </GetCategories>
```

## Code

```
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $dom->loadXML($response->toXML());  
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;

        $Xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

        foreach ($Xpath->evaluate('/GetCategories/GetProduct/Data/Top[1]') as $data) 
         {
            $type = $data->appendChild($dom->createElement('TypeId'));
            $type->appendChild($dom->createTextNode('HDU5K3KDI23F'));
         }

           $dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
           $xmldata = $dom->saveXML();
           echo $xmldata;

        $myfile = file_put_contents('data.xml', $xmldata.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: FILE_APPEND will break the xml: Good: https://3v4l.org/Tds8t Bad: https://3v4l.org/SMOft

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add node to a XML variable and Save it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52079003/add-node-to-a-xml-variable-and-save-it)

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone, actually data is in loop so it is appending the file inside the same file...and i think that why this code is not working...the way you did i working for me too, but for me i have an array of IDs and  i want to add these IDs as node to the xml and save it, then again take the next id and looping the same thing and  appending in the same file.

Comment: Dont append it as saveXML includes the header which will break it. If your looping then load the file, loop over the GetProduct's, add the id, then save.

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone, Ohk so you  are saying that let the whole process gets complete...then load the xml file and loop over the GetProducts's, add the id, the save.Right.?

Comment: Yeah, show a real example, of the data you want to insert into the xml (as your dont want to insert the same id in all elements) and ill post an answer.

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone,Please have a look i have added the complete head of a final file and also a array of data that i want to add... 3v4l.org/8lL1O

Answer (score 0):

Change the code in foreach as follows:
First create element with value and append to your data.

```
foreach ($Xpath->evaluate('/GetCategories/GetProduct/Data/Top[1]') as $data) 
{
    $type = $dom->createElement('TypeId', 'HDU5K3KDI23F');
    $data->appendChild($type);
}
```